# How to get familiarized with certificate generation

Tags: web-services, certificate

I am supposed to work on web Services (using  Apache CXF and Spring )

I was asked to get familiarized with certificate generation, as we will need to generate certificates going forward for the web services.

One thing I knew is that  they are using Glassfish server.

I googled , but I didn't understand anything.

I know that the information I provided is not sufficient, to expect a relevant answer

But Could anybody please let me know , what will be the best starting point on this ?? and what other information should we need from the client to make it clearer ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To secure web services you can use PKI (private key infrastructure), this uses asymmetric keys, a key pair with the property that what a key encrypt only the other one decrypt. This key pair is composed by a private and a public key. usually a certificate is generated for a public key, in order to identify the key owner. You can use **keytool** or **openSSL** to generate keys and certificates. I made this fast introduction just to throw some keywords that you can search for.

In a fast search i found this, maybe help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724631/understanding-keystore-certificates-and-alias

If you need anymore help, I can get you more information.

Comment: In order to help you with anything more, you need to ask more concrete questions.